# MySQL WHERE 'all' when no value supplied

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am writing a tool to search through different records in my database, where you have to specify the year. However, if no year value is entered, or is equal to zero, I want to be able to select all records.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM performances WHERE year = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $year);
```

I have tried to do if statements, but they fail because then there are more parameters in bind_param than spaces in the query, m.sh:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * 
                          FROM performances
                          . (($year != 0) ? " WHERE year = ? " : " ")
                          . "");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $year);
```

Thanks

Comment: How about you use a conditional and only bind params if there are params to bind?

Comment: If no year is entered, why not just do this: `SELECT * FROM performances`?

Comment: I have 5 different variables that could be set to 'all' or a specific id, so if statements would need 120 different combinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in different ways, like:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM performances WHERE year = :year or 0 = :year");
$stmt->bind_param("year", $year);
```

Comment: Works so far, but how would I extend this for going through more than one variable (like team, season and venue, etc.)?

Comment: should be straight forward by adding other parameters
`$stmt->bind_param("team", $team);`
and update the query as 
`$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM performances WHERE (year = :year or 0 = :year) and (team= :team or 0 = :team) ");`

Comment: Didn't realise you could use bind_param more than once, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ShyForNow has a pretty good answer. I'd also recommend to validate inputs going into SQL:

```
$year = sprintf("%d", $year); -- or even throw exception if $year is not numeric

if ($year > 0)    -- or could also write if ($year >= $minAcceptableYear and $year <= $maxAcceptableYear)
{
   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM performances WHERE year = ?");
   $stmt->bind_param("i", $year);
} 
else 
{
   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM performances");
}
```